# Testing Web API Controllers?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I really have no experience with unit testing, but I have tried to implement a very simple one into my application and can't get it to run. I have a .NET Web API with a controller I would like to test. I have crated the following test class in a separate project, and referenced the API in it:

```
[TestClass]
class TestWebhookControllers
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestTest_ShouldReturn201()
    {
        var controller = new TestWebhookController();
        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

        var result = controller.Get();

        Assert.AreEqual(result.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.Continue);
    }
}
```

When I click on run all tests, the build succeeds but nothing else happens. The Test Explorer is empty. There are no errors of any kind. I must be missing something basic.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to make the class public for it to be picked up

```
[TestClass]
public class TestWebhookControllers
```